# Как при клике по # скрывать адаптивное меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня есть адаптивное меню. Например: когда находишься на странице и переходишь по ссылке #, это окно не закрывается - как это можно исправить?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".menu-toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
    $(".navigation-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 0 80px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.header-inner-width {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.logo img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}

.navigation-menu{
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90px;
}

.navigation-menu a{
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.navigation-menu a:hover{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.navigation-menu i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.home-icon {
  color: #ff6b6b;
}

.about-icon{
  color: #0abde3;
}

.blog-icon {
  color: #feca57;
}

.price-icon {
  color: #5f27cd;
}

.contact-icon {
  color: #1dd1a1;
}

.menu-toggle-btn{
  float: right;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px !important;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
 .header {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }
 .menu-toggle-btn{
  display: block !important;
 }

 .navigation-menu {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  top: 142px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .navigation-menu::before{
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 18px;
 }

 .navigation-menu a{
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
 }

 .navigation-menu.active{
  display: block;
 }
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
 .header {
  padding: 0 10px;
 }
 .menu-toggle-btn{
  display: block !important;
 }

 .navigation-menu {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  top: 142px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .navigation-menu::before{
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 18px;
 }

 .navigation-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
 }

 .navigation-menu.active{
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header-inner-width">
    <a href="../pages/index.php" class="logo"><img src="../img/logo_white.png" alt=""></a>
    <i class="menu-toggle-btn fas fa-bars"></i>
    <nav class="navigation-menu">
      <a href="../pages/index.php"><i class="fas fa-home home-icon"></i>Главная</a>
      <a href="../pages/index.php#about"><i class="fas fa-align-left about-icon"></i> О нас</a>
      <a href="../pages/blog.php"><i class="fab fa-buffer blog-icon"></i> Блог</a>
      <a href="../pages/market.php#market"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd price-icon"></i>Прайс</a>
      <a href="../pages/feedback.php"><i class="fas fa-headset contact-icon"></i>Контакты</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

P.S: допустим если находишься в index.php и переходишь на index.php#about
Выдает вот так:
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".menu-toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
    $(".navigation-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".navigation-menu a").click(function(){
    $('.menu-toggle-btn.fa-times').removeClass("fa-times");
    $(".navigation-menu.active").removeClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Kimsq Если ваша проблема решена, отметьте решение.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы на странице `index.php` нажимаете ссылку `index.php#about`, вы не загружаете новую страницу, а прокручиваете текущую страницу до якоря `#about`. Соответственно, меню остается `.active`, так как страница осталась та же, а убирание `.active` при клике по ссылке с якорем у вас не прописано.

Answer (score 0):

Отслеживать нажатие по ссылке и при нажатии закрывать меню:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    // Здесь пишем код, который будет закрывать меню
})
```